# subversion mysteriously getting disconnected

Tags: apache-http-server, svn

We have installed Subversion 1.7.2 with Apache 2.2 on a Windows 2008R2 VM server. And for authentication, svn is integrated with Active directory. We are facing a very strange problem. After 2-3 days of accessing svn, it suddenly becomes inaccessible from svn clients. While accessing the repository url it throws a 500 error. The log file doesn't show any error message. Apache seems to be running as well.

We tried to restart the Apache server but doesn't resolve. Neither apache log nor windows event log show any message its tough to debug. The only way we have found is by restarting the server box. This is very embarrassing.

Has anyone faced similar issue? its an Apache issue or svn issue?

We are now absolutely clue less and planning to upgrade the svn to a higher version but we don't know which version has the fix.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue. It's 3 years later now, but I found this so-question on google..
I did change nothing and it worked for years without problems and suddenly I get an error 500. Reboot or explicitly restarting svn or apache service does not help.